# Post to facebook company page using sharekit

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sharekit

Hope someone out there can help.

I'm developing an IOS app using sharekit to access facebook. The app needs the user to post to his/her facebook page and the post should also appear on the clients company/brand page.

I have create a test company page through the following page ... http://www.facebook.com/pages/create/

using  sharekit i have been able to post without any errors to the company page using its id. But these post do not appear on the company page.

is it possible to post to both a users and a company page using sharekit?

Any pointers would be great

thanks in advance